# Data grouping and sub-grouping by column variable in R

Tags: r, grouping, export-to-csv

I am working on data collection by **R** on Win7.

The given data is:

```
  var1    var2   value
```

I need to do grouping by var1 and then for each var1 , do grouping by var2.

Then, the output  is column vectors of values that are associated with the same var1 and var2. Here, var1 and var2 are like keys.

Example,

```
   var1    var2   value
   1          56       649578   
   2          17       357835
   1          88       572397
   2          90       357289
   1          56       427352   
   2          17       498455
   1          88       354623
   2          90       678658
```

The result should be

```
   var1    var2   value
   1          56       649578   
   1          56       427352   
   1          88       354623
   1          88       572397
   2          17       357835
   2          17       498455
   2          90       357289
   2          90       678658
```

And, I need to print the values in a CSV file as

For var 1 as 1:

```
   649578   354623
   427352   572397
```

For var 1 as 2:

```
  357835   357289
  498455   678658
```

And, I also  need to print the values in a CSV file as

For var 1 = 1:

```
   1          56       649578   
   1          56       427352   
   1          88       354623
   1          88       572397
```

For var1  = 2:

```
   2          17       357835
   2          17       498455
   2          90       357289
   2          90       678658
```

How to do it ?

I found some posts, which are not directly useful.

---

**Update:**
How to choose and print the values that are associated with each unique var2 ?

Are there dictionary data structure in **R**?

Comment: Do you need individual CSV files for all var1 var2 combinations? i.e. for the last two sections above can these be in 1 CSV and just have the ordered output by var1, var2?

Comment: @Steve Reno, var1 var2 combinations can be put in one file. Thanks!

Comment: are there always exactly 2 values of var2 for each value of var1 (as your example implies) or do they vary?

Comment: @Steve Reno, for each var1, var2 may have many different values. Thanks !

Comment: To sort your data (assume it is `t`) by `var1` and then by `var2`: `t[with(t, order(var1,var2)),]`

Answer (score 0):

This is relatively close to what you are looking for I believe, but not quite the same. It should provide some help though

```
library(reshape2)
library(plyr)

dat<-data.frame(var1=c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2),var2=c(56,17,88,90,56,17,88,90),value=c(649578,357835,572397,357289,427352,498455,354623,678658))

dat<-dat[order(dat$var1,dat$var2),]

dat<-ddply(dat,.(var1,var2),summarize,seq1=c(1:length(value)),value=value)

dat.new.new<-dcast(dat,var1+var2~seq1,value.var="value")
```

the second dat call using order() will order the results as you requested, and the dat.new.new data frame is close to what you were looking for.

bonus points for catching the KidCudi reference

Comment: I will tryit, Also, when I read the data, I found that for floating point numbers, the didgits after decimal point are cut off. How to keep them ? Thanks

Comment: also, i need to count the size of each sub-group. I need to know how many numbers are in each sub0group. Thanks !