# Print data column associated with the same column variable values in R

Tags: r, dataframe, hash, grouping

I am working on data collection by **R** on Win7

This is related to my previous question:
[Data grouping and sub-grouping by column variable in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22048990/data-grouping-and-sub-grouping-by-column-variable-in-r)

I have this data frame.

```
var1    var2   value
1          56       649578   
1          56       427352   
1          88       354623
1          88       572397
2          17       357835
2          17       498455
2          90       357289
2          90       678658
```

I need to print them in CSV file as:

```
649578   354623   357835  357289
427352   572397   498455  678658
```

I need to use dictionary or hashset in **R**?

Answer (score 1):

Here's your data, again, just for reproducibility:

```
mydf <- read.table(text='var1    var2   value
1          56       649578   
1          56       427352   
1          88       354623
1          88       572397
2          17       357835
2          17       498455
2          90       357289
2          90       678658', header=TRUE)
```

Take a look at the documentation for [`write.table`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/write.table.html).

You say you want a CSV, which would look like the following:

```
write.csv(matrix(mydf$value, nrow=2), 'test.csv')
```

Produces "test.csv":

```
"","V1","V2","V3","V4"
"1",649578,354623,357835,357289
"2",427352,572397,498455,678658
```

Or, I think you probably want:

```
write.table(matrix(mydf$value, nrow=2), 'test.tsv', sep='\t')
```

Produces "test.tsv":

```
"V1"    "V2"    "V3"    "V4"
"1" 649578  354623  357835  357289
"2" 427352  572397  498455  678658
```